# Assign running number based on row entries R

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably something very easy for you guys. As indicated in the title, I would like to create a new column having running numbers based on row entries from a different column (in this case ASV column). So the row entries in reference column has duplicate values.

```
 ASV                   New_column 
 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j     1 
 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j     1
 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j     1 
 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7     2 
 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7     2 
 1387341yqfysddhas394h     3
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

If we assume your data frame is named 'dat' we can use the following code:

```
dat$New_column <- as.integer(factor(dat$ASV))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**
I decided to come up with another solution as `rleid` may lead to misleading result.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(dup = +duplicated(df$ASV),
         id = cumsum(dup == 0)) %>%
  select(-dup)

                    ASV id
1 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j  1
2 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j  1
3 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j  1
4 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7  2
5 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7  2
6 1387341yqfysddhas394h  3
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `match`

```
dat$New_column <- with(data, match(ASV, unique(ASV)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If new ids are to be allocated alphabetically, `dense_rank` in `dplyr` can be used

```
df %>% mutate(New_column = dense_rank(ASV))

                    ASV New_column
1 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j          3
2 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j          3
3 wthjjwjjgbwurigwe434j          3
4 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7          2
5 21y4hghgw6yw8ngqoigj7          2
6 1387341yqfysddhas394h          1
```

OR

```
df %>% group_by(ASV) %>%
  mutate(New_column = cur_group_id())
```